# Why is This bool value needed and exactly how is it being used?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm practicing using loops using boolean values and saw this code. I'm not sure why this code needs "bool finished = 0;" or how it's being used in the while loop, alongside "continue;". If I can get any help id to be grateful

```
#include "input.c"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool GetYesOrNoInput() {

  std::string response;
  bool finished = 0;

  std::cin >> response;

  while (!(finished)) {
    if (response == "yes") {
      return true;
    } else if (response == "no") {
      return false;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Sorry, I didnt understand. try again: ";
      cin >> response;
      continue;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bad code. Don't try to understand this. Learn C++ with good C++ books and good codes in them.

Comment: `finished` never changes, so that `while` is an infinite loop which can only end with one of the `return` statements. The `continue;` is redundant. The last `return 0;` can never be reached, and if it were then `return false;` would have been better, anyway. All in all, not the kind of code that you should be studying for practice.

Comment: Also, `#include "input.c"`? Not only should a C file not be included, but I also don't see any outside function being used anywhere here.

Comment: `finished` is used to create an infinite loop. It is (logically) similar to saying `while(true)`, but it doesn't seem to be well written. The `continue` at the end of loop has no relevance since there are no statements after that in the loop. Also the `return 0` at the end is also unreachable.

Comment: By default, if not initialised, a variable of automatic storage duration is uninitialised, and accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.  `bool finished = 0` has the effect of initialising `finished` to be `false`.   It would be more clearly expressed as `bool finished = false`.   In the code, as written, `finished` is not accessed in the loop body, so its usage in the code is unnecessary.   Presumably some previous version of the code did something useful with `finished` in the loop body.

Comment: This presents a bit of a quandary. It's a bad question, but I can understand why the asker's confused by this code and don't want to see the asker potentially run into a see a question ban with this as a contributing question.

Comment: Suggestion: Next time, try and turn the question into a flowchart or some other visualization aid. It could help you see dead, redundant or otherwise goofy code.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure why this code needs "bool finished = 0;" or how it's being used in the while loop, alongside "continue;".

None of these things are necessary, but they are also not incorrect. In a code review of *new* C++, I would reject this, and in existing code I would want to change it.

`bool finished = 0;` initialises `finished` to `false`. Historically, in C, there was not a boolean type, so `int` was used. 0 represented false, and all other numbers represented true. C++ still allows code like this by implicitly converting `int` values to `bool` values.

`while (!(finished))` is a condition that is always true, because `finished` is never changed. This means the loop will repeat until one of the `return` statements are reached.

`continue` ends the current iteration of the loop early, with the program going back to checking the loop condition. Because there is nothing after this `continue`, it has no effect.